# Java: Cannot write to socket after socket in.readLine()

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am turning to you StackOverflow, I have been butting my head against the wall on this one.

I am doing a little socket programming and I can see when I put the out.println("...") line of code BEFORE the while loop (the in.readLine()) it works correctly, but I need it to be inside the loop.

To be clear, I do not see any errors.  I just don't see the text appear on the client-side of this application.  It looks as if it is working, but it is not. Also, I do not control the client-side of this either, it is handled by a device that connects via TCP to this Socket Listener application.  It it possible that it severs the connection as soon as the data is read?

```
public class ConnectionHandlerTCP implements Runnable
{
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        ConnectionHandlerTCP(Socket socket)
        {
                clientSocket = socket;
        }

        public void run()
        {
                int uniqueId = 0;
                try (
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                ){
                        String inputLine;

                        // This Line WORKS, I see it appear on the other side of the connection.
                        Log.debug("Sending now A");
                        out.println("text to send here");

                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                                // This Line DOES NOT WORK, I do not see it on the other side of the connection.
                                //Log.debug("Sending now B");
                                //out.println("text to send here");

                                // ... bunch of commented out code here
                        }

                        in.close();
                        out.close();
                        clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.error("Exception caught when trying to read input.", e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.error("Exception caught when trying to parse data.", e.getMessage());
                }
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  In case it is helpful, here is the main class.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SocketListenerTCP 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        while(true)
        {
            try ( 
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            ) {

                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                new Thread(new ConnectionHandlerTCP(clientSocket)).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.error("Exception caught", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I simplified it a little more, took out the loop completely and this is still not working correctly.

```
                inputLine = in.readLine();
                Log.debug(inputLine);  

                Log.debug("Sending now");
                out.println("text to send here");
```

Comment: It sounds like the peer isn't sending terminated lines at all, so you shouldn't be using `readLine()`. Check your application protocol.

Comment: @user207421, I do not see it in the documentation, but I also believe they are not sending a return-character at all.  Which was the source of all my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside

`while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)`

is most likely not running because `in.readLine` keeps on waiting for an input from the client.

The client program/socket needs to have it's on `PrintWriter` and `println` something so that your `while` loop can read it and respond (assuming that's what you're intending to achieve).

Comment: But I can see that it does, in fact, get inside the loop.  I see the logged line "Log.debug("Sending now B");" occur.  I can log the "inputLine" and see that it does have the string/data that I expect it to have.

Are you saying the PrinterWriter line should be inside the loop?   [I don't think that is what you are saying, just clarifying]

Comment: Does it make any kind of sense that perhaps the device I am connecting to kills the connection once the data is read via the "readline" function?  I am VERY rusty on socket programming, so I am not even sure if that makes reasonable sense.

Comment: What's the device you're connecting to? Yes it's possible that the device just quits after sending a message one time.
Your code as itself (at least the first snippet you posted) is fine.

Comment: I simplified it a little more, took out the loop completely and this is still not working correctly.  

                        inputLine = in.readLine();
                        Log.debug(inputLine);  

                        Log.debug("Sending now");
                        out.println("text to send here");

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I finally figured out the crux of my issue.  First off to explain my original problem.  I am convinced now that the device I am connecting to disconnects from my server application after 20 seconds (or so) of no activity being read/written.   So readline() will wait for that 20s to be up, then returns whatever it has, and there is no writing back to the device allowed at that time.   However, if I read all the characters one at a time (via read()), it works just fine, allows me to read the whole message and waits on the last character read iteration of the read() loop for the final "-1" to come through, signaling the end of payload.   Between that time (reading the first character and the waiting for the last character), I parse the payload and send anything I want to the device.  Which for the most part it receives.

My secondary problem was that sometimes the output streams would appear to be disconnected and never let me send any messages anymore.  In the original code, I made the class implement "Runnable".  This was a mistake.   I saw all over the place that using Runnable was the preferred way to do it, but I noticed that the OutputStream would rarely work in this case, I switched over to extending the Thread class and it works nearly 100% of the time.   I believe the one thread was over-writing the output stream of the other, then the next thread doing the same thing and then each of the threads was unable to communicate through the output stream.

After looking at some other examples online, I am assuming there is some way that I could use Runnable if I wanted to, but would have to refactor some other items in my application.  I'll have to do some more reading before I go back down that road.

In any case, it seems to be running smoothly for the time being and only rarely fails now.   I would still love to know why it still fails on occasion, so I will continue to look into that as time permits.

I am a little baffled still by one of the commenters saying that I couldn't read and write on the same thread...that seems to be completely untrue and reading and writing seems to work just fine, so long as a I read() first (as opposed to readLine()) before I write to the device.

Comment: You should submit a new question if you have new details on your problem. Users generally browse recent questions and a new question is more likely to be answered.

Comment: The -1 indicates the end of the *stream,* i.e. the disconnection, not the end of the payload. It sounds like the peer isn't sending terminated lines at all, so you shouldn't be using `readLine()`.

Comment: Thanks @user207421, I agree, but I didn't know that till long after I started writing that.  I stopped using readline() in my most recent code and it appears to be working correctly.

AlainMerigot, I will submit a new one if necessary.  At this point I think I am in good shape.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Reading the InputStream of a socket connection is thread blocking. You can not read and write at the same time within the same thread. Move the Printwriter in another thread and you should be fine.

Comment: I don't know that I believe that...because if I write to the socket first, then read it works exactly how I would expect.   But if I reverse it and read first, then attempt to write, it seems like it goes no where.

Comment: Yes that behavior is correct. If you write to the socket first, you are not reading the socket at that moment. Writing is not thread blocking, but reading is. Because the thread is always listening on the socket for new incoming messages.

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution? @LebowskiT1000

Comment: Well, I found a way around my issue, but it's far from ideal.   I noticed that I could read the data one character at a time and get the entire message, get the information from that that I needed (which I used to determine what information is going to be written back), then wrote the information in the socket.   THEN, I read the entire message with the readLine().  

So, I have discovered that IF I wait till the readLine() completes, I cannot write back to the device on the socket.  BUT if I read the message enough to determine what device I am talking to, using "read()", that works.

Comment: I also noticed that there seems to be a fair amount of time (20 seconds) between making the connection to the device and being able to read the entire message with readLine()....when I read one character at a time, it is instantaneous.  It is as if my side of the listening is not allowed to read the whole message until the device-side says "ok, you may read it now, and I am done"